# How to make a <select> dropdown behave like <input type='file'> while pointing to files on a remote server?

Tags: html, angular, input, file-io, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to update a feature in an Angular app. The feature basically is you provide a file from your local drive, the app does some processing, and then offers the modified file for download. The current implementation has you provide the file by clicking on an `<input type='file'>` element on the page and then selecting one from your local drive using your browser/OS's standard file explorer.

I'd like the exact same process except that instead of requiring the user to offer the input file from their local drive, they would be able to select from a few input files using a dropdown (like a select input). The files they'd choose from would not be from their local drive, but pulled from a remote location.

The reason it currently uses `<input type='file'>` is because it provides easy access to that file in JavaScript. The filename, extension, and contents are pulled into JavaScript variables using `FileReader()`:

```
let file_button = document.querySelector('#file-input')
let file = file_button.files[0]
let file_name = file.name

if (file.type !== 'text/html') {
    alert('must be HTML file')
}

let content;
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');

reader.onload = event => {
    content = event.target.result;
}
```

I need to be able to do these kinds of operations, but using a `<select>` style dropdown, and I need to be able to pull the files into the client (JavaScript) from the server, rather than from the user's local drive.

Comment: This can't be done with pure Javascript.  You will need backend support.  What are you using for your backend?

Comment: Assuming you can receive the file blob from the server in some sort of list, you can then iterate over the list and use the JavaScript File() constructor to create a File for each item. You should then be able to use this with FileReader() as you are already doing.